# What does caret(^) in Oracle translate function mean?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I encountered this statement from other developer's code which returns `ABCDEF`:

```
SELECT TRANSLATE('ABC123DEF456', '^0123456789', '^') FROM DUAL;
```

Then I tested with the following which have the same result:

```
SELECT TRANSLATE('ABC123DEF456', '^0123456789', ' ') FROM DUAL;
SELECT TRANSLATE('ABC123DEF456', '0123456789', ' ') FROM DUAL;
```

But this one returns null:

```
SELECT TRANSLATE('ABC123DEF456', '0123456789', '') FROM DUAL;
```

What does caret(`^`) mean? Why is it necessary?

Comment: think it means match from the beginning

Comment: @haki, it appears in the replacement string (the last parameter), so I don' think it is a regex here.

Comment: It doesn't actually make any difference - you can use `^`, or `A`, or whatever - as long as it's not one of the characters that you want to remove.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`TRANSLATE(expr, from_string, to_string)`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions216.htm#SQLRF06145):

> You cannot use an empty string for `to_string` to remove all characters
>   in `from_string` from the return value. Oracle Database interprets the
>   empty string as null, and if this function has a null argument, then
>   it returns null.

Thus you cannot specify `''` as the value for the `to_string` parameter, because it would be interpreted as null.

I suspect `^` is used here because it will never appear in the `expr`, and thus you will never see it in the resulting string as in `TRANSLATE('ABC12^3DE0F456', '^0123456789', '^')` which returns `ABC^DEF`.

Your original function `SELECT TRANSLATE('ABC123DEF456', '^0123456789', '^') FROM DUAL;` effectively strips all digits from the source string because for every matching digit in `from_string` there's no corresponding character in `to_string`, the other characters are just ignored.

Comment: Reasonable. But what is the benefit of  using `^`? Why not simple using space char like this:   SELECT TRANSLATE('ABC123DEF456', '0123456789', ' ') FROM DUAL;

Comment: With `TRANSLATE('ABC1230DEF456', '0123456789', ' ')`, you'll get `0` substituted with white space instead of just removing it: `ABC DEF`.